# How to get all the files modified in the branch after a specified date from VSTS api?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to find all the files modified in a branch after a specific date from the VSTS rest API. I need to create a report based on this.

I found the endpoint that returns all the files in the branch, but how do I find the file modification date time or only the files modified after a specific date?

The endpoint to get all files from a branch is given below

```
GET https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_apis/git/repositories/8b07c923-7876-47fb-b234-4587564/items?recursionLevel=full&includeContentMetadata=true&latestProcessedChange=false&download=false&includeLinks=true&versionDescriptor.versionType=branch&versionDescriptor.version=Releasexxxx&api-version=4.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Get all the commits in a brach after a specific date via [Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1) first and then get all the changed files in the commits via [Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20changes?view=vsts-rest-4.1).